# Problem with insert WFS-T for multi polygon layer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openlayers, wfs-t

I am trying to do an  insert WFS-T into PostGis Data store multi-polygon layer with post request:

```
   <Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Insert><polygon xmlns="http://spatial_editing"><geometry><MultiPolygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><polygonMember><Polygon><exterior><LinearRing><posList>8312679.700069487 1823481.746771165 8289442.843470794 1774562.048668652 8353038.451004061 1796575.912814783 8312679.700069487 1823481.746771165</posList></LinearRing></exterior></Polygon></polygonMember></MultiPolygon></geometry></polygon></Insert></Transaction>
```

After this there is a new entry in the Datastore table, but the_geom is 
empty. It looks like this SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON ((EMPTY)).

Comment: Have you verified that your WFS-T POST is standard compliant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your column is called the_geom, and your WFS request uses geometry. Make sure they match so it needs to be the_geom in your POST XML as well.

Comment: as per your suggestion I have changed column name to geometry in database.still same problem exists

Comment: now its storing value but its not reflecting on layers

Comment: i have solve by changing projection.Now its working perfectly.Thank you